# Getting build failure while deploying azure function

Tags: azure, function, deployment, oryx

While trying to deploy a azure function from vs code getting build failure.
function is tested and working fine in local and giving output as expected.
pip install requirments.txt command is also passed.

[image]

Comment: Please share your Function App's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

**I followed below steps to deploy Python Azure Function to Azure Function App.**

- Created a Python Azure Function with version 3.11 locally.
- Add setting `"AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"` & `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"` in `local.settings.json`:

**local.settings.json:**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}
```

- Created a Function App with Python as runtime stack (version 3.11) in Azure Portal.

**Configuration:**

[image]

- ***Deployed the function app to Azure using Visual Studio Code successfully:***

[image]

- If the issue still persists, you can try deploying with **Azure CLI**.

  - Make sure you have installed ***Azure function core tools***.
  - If not, install with the command `npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools --unsafe-perm true`

[image]

- Use the below command to deploy the functionapp to Azure:
  `func azure functionapp publish <functionapp_name> --build remote`.

[image]

- ***Able to deploy successfully:***

[image]